Blocked by Flood • braziliancep python
I'm creating a update of latlon on my table, but i am blocked. Someone knows how can I fix that without losing too much time?
My table have 54000 rows.
I just tried using time.sleep(20)
my code bellow:
import time         as tm
import pandas       as pa
import numpy        as nu
import brazilcep    as bc
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

coord = pa.read_csv("Arquivos\\Coordenadas.csv",sep = ";")

for index, row in coord.iterrows():
    # Obter os valores do CEP, Latitude e Longitude
        
    cep = row["CEP"]
    latitude = row["LATITUDE"]
    longitude = row["LONGITUDE"]
    tm.sleep(10)
    
    # Passar o CEP pelo filtro
    endereco = bc.get_address_from_cep(cep)
    ad = endereco["street"].split("-")[0],endereco["city"]
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
    location = geolocator.geocode(ad)
    lat = (location.latitude)
    lon = (location.longitude)
    
    # Substituir os valores de Latitude e Longitude pelo valor de Lat Lon
    coord.at[index, "LATITUDE"] = lat
    coord.at[index, "LONGITUDE"] = lon

    tm.sleep(10)
    

# Salvar o DataFrame modificado de volta para o arquivo CSV
coord.to_csv("Arquivos\\Coordenadas_Atualizadas.csv", index=False)


You are getting blocked because brazilcep underlying API has a rate limit, which times you out after several requests within a period.
I would not even recommend using an API for it. It would be better to download the database from CEP Aberto or another source and use it locally to update your CSV.
Another alternative would be to implement other APIs (that probably will also have rate limits) and do logic to distribute the load between them. But downloading and processing a local database would be way easier.
I hope this can help a fellow Brazilian :)

I'll try do this using CEP Aberto, but using the API can I just make less requests  for API don't block me?

You could try to use a more responsive API other than apicep, which is the source from brazilcep library blocking you. I did some tests and ViaCEP seems way more responsive. You can try to do something like this: https://gist.github.com/felipenovais/b8535bbcae83aab519cd25096672669c

If values in CEP columns appear more than once you might use @functools.cache to keep already retrieved data in memory. For example
import functools
import brazilcep as bc


@functools.cache
def get_address_with_memory(cep):
    return bc.get_address_from_cep(cep)


data_1 = get_address_with_memory('37503-130')
data_2 = get_address_with_memory('37503-130')
data_3 = get_address_with_memory('37503-130')

Will query once (first call).
If you want to know more about such appreach read about memoization

i do this, its very helpfull but my problem with API remains. Thanks
